# How to add "ADD TO COMPARE" link in custom phtml in magento?

Tags: magento-2.1.8

I have added custom phtml and displayed the products information. Now, I want to add the link "ADD TO COMPARE" for the products.

Answer (score 3):

```
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare

/**
 * @var compareProductHelper
 */
protected $compareProductHelper;


/**     
 * @param compareProductHelper $compareProductHelper     
 */
public function __construct(        
    Compare $compareProductHelper,        
) {

    $this->compareProductHelper = $compareProductHelper;

}
```

Now you can get compare `product` url like this,

```
$compareUrl=$this->compareProductHelper->getPostDataParams($product);
```

Where `$product` is `product` object (`Magento\Catalog\Model\Product`)

Comment: Yes, are right. I removed my answer. also, +10 for your answer.

Comment: Thanks for +1, you can also update your answer without deleting. Also, happy to see that your contribution towards community through module and answer s:) @PrincePatel